# Find Columns in range

Tags: excel, vba, vsto, excel-interop

Is it possible to know which columns are present in a range of given Columns
e.g "A:C"   there are columns A,B and C 
e.g "G:K"   there is column G,H,I,J and K
and for "Z:AC"    there is Z,AA,AB and AC

I am using C# and com iterop

Comment: I am trying get_range but getting an exception
so i am searching for it

Comment: Curiosity: why is this tagged VBA if C# is being used?

Comment: @Aashay to get an idea or hint: because similar properties are available in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;   
'
'
'
xlRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1:C10", misValue);
int rw = xlRange.Cells[1, 1].Column;

for (int i = 1; i <= xlRange.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,rw].Address.Split('$')[1]);
    rw ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use alphabets as base 26 numbers. This will help to find the position of AA or AZ or A. Hope this helps.